# how to reset router without reset button?

Tags: router

I was trying to enable mac filtering and now I can't access internet, the reset button is broken, is there a way to reset the router or bypass the mac filtering?

Comment: You can change the mac address your client is advertising. The way to do this depends on your OS.

Comment: @Arminius I don't understand, this is my router, I have a RJ45 Connector I can connect it to the router and my computer, I am using windows 10. can you please explaine to me what I need to do?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what kind of mac filter you enabled? As I understand it, you accidentally blacklisted the MAC of your Windows machine.

Comment: I was trying to block access to network of a mac adresse I select deny traffic and I clicked add, what I think I should have done is to first allow my adresse then deny the other one, now no device is connected in my home.

Comment: open the shell and work around the broken button; short the traces leading to the button to "press" it.

Answer (score 1):

Does your router have a power button? In some cases, holding down the power button functions as a reset.

It might help if you told us what kind of router it is.

Comment: it did not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure the reset button is broken? If so, you may have to try the method @Arminius suggested.

Comment: I don't know how to do that? can you please explain how?

Comment: This webpage has instructions on how to do it on Windows and OS X: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address/

Answer (score 0):

If you are out of warranty on your router, open the case and locate where the wires or the solder of the reset button lead. You could short it like powering on a PC without the case (do it at your risk, you could fry the router if you short some other connection on the circuit board).